# Flask comunicação ajax html

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Gostaria de uma ajuda com uma aplicação em Python utilizando o framework Flask, estou querendo enviar dados para o html ,e depois mostrar esses dados em uma tabela.

a função do flask :

```py
@myapp.route('/treino', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def treinar_modelo():
    scoreF, scoreSV, scoreA = mdF, mdSV, mdA
    listascore = [scoreF, scoreSV, scoreA]
    return jsonify({'data': render_template('index.html', listascore=listascore)})
```

A parte do javascript que tem que receber os dados
a partir de um botão que for clicado, esses dados devem ir para uma tabela

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('button#md').click(function(){
          e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            url: "/treino",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                $('table#score').append(resp.data);
            }
        });
      });
```

A parte do html , o botao a ser apertado e a tabela a ser preenchido a partir dos dados que eu vou obter advindos da função em python , eu sei que está faltando coisas e que a maior parte do codigo está errado , gostaria muito de uma orientação :

```html
<form action="" method="POST" >
  <button onclick="" id="md"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="treinar" name="treinar" >Treinar modelo  <i style="font-family: FontAwesome !important;" class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
  </form>
</a>
</nav>

<table  style=" text-align: center; align: center; valign: middle; border: 15px solid white; border-top:none; border-bottom:none; opacity : 0.7;" class="table table-dark " id="score" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Floresta aleatória</th>
      <th scope="col">Support vector machine </th>
      <th scope="col">Árvore de decisão</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>


                {% for score in listascore %}
      <td><output  >  {{  score  }}  </output></td>

      <td><output  >  {{  score }}  </output></td>

      <td><output  >  {{  score  }}</output></td>
                     {% endfor %}

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso você vai ter que renderizar a tabela pelo javascript e não pelo html tem uma função chamada innerHtml, da uma olhada nela.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Eu não estou sabendo usar esta função que foi recomendada  , você poderia me ajudar com um exemplo?